# Unable to set drupal_set_message() after logout redirect

Tags: 8, redirection, status-messages

I want to show a message via `drupal_set_message()` after logout and redirects to page.

Code:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_user_logout().
 */
function example_user_logout($account){
  $login_message = 'You have been redirected';
  drupal_set_message(t($login_message));
  $login_redirect = '/mypage';
  example_redirect($login_redirect);
}

/**
 * Redirect path for logout.
 */
function example_redirect($path) {
  $response = new RedirectResponse($path);
  $response->send();
  exit;
}
```

Tried commenting exit also, but still no luck.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: Yes, but different method.
Passing query parameter and displaying message.
After displaying message, unsetting the parameter to not shown second time.

Comment: Thank you Ajay. And how are you unsetting parameter? Using javascript or server side code? Can you share?

Comment: First while creating token i am saving in my custom table and deleting after displaying message

Answer (score 4):

`drupal_set_message()` sets the message in `$_SESSION`. By logging out, you destroy the current session and thus wipe the message you just set.

Comment: ok, is there any way to display message after logout?

Comment: Only way I can think of, is putting a parameter along in the redirect, like 'action=logout' or such, and check for that parameter when loading the page you redirect users to. The main issue here is you can't use sessions for this, so you'll have to find a way around that. My suggestion here is one option, but I'm sure there are more.

Comment: Raf: I can set parameter but I don't want to see the message over and over when user refresh the same page (with argument). Is that possible?

Comment: Those messages are cleared from `$_SESSION` the moment they're shown. In other words: unless you set the same message on every page load, it won't show over and over when the user refreshes the same page.

Comment: Drupal 7 solution
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2009-06-15/show-you-are-now-signed-out-message#comment-12589557

You can do similar with Drupal 8 and routes.